# Can I get an @Output out of a pug mixin?

Tags: angular, output, mixins, angular2-template, pug

So I'm using Angular 2 with pug as template, with a little mail subscription form as a component. I wanted this component to send the form value (the email) as an @Output, so my AppComponent can consume the value in the method to actually subscribe the user.

This newsletter component's output would be accessed by using the getter in the pug:

```
newsletter-form((onSubscribed)="subscribeMail($event)")
```

This is perfect and I can get the value in the App, except I took this NewsletterComponent out of the app directly, to put it in a pug mixin, as a footer.

So now the AppComponent can't grab a hold of the value anymore, since the form's template is not directly in the App's template anymore... Is it possible for me to access the value of the output in this mixin?

maybe an output in the mixin... i don't know...

I know i can use the form component directly, but it would hurt my architecture and would not be.. well, pretty.

Thanks in advance

Comment: use a service :) always use a service to communicate between not parent/child components. It's clean and effective

Comment: That's actually a good idea! i will give it a shot, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. It should work, but it looked like the mixin was out of the App closure. Actually what happened was that the mixin was updated, but the app template was not, so the App didn't get the changes, because of the differential compilation.

Changing the template and saving it (causing it to recompile) solved the problem and the AppComponent got the @Outuput value seamlessly.

Kind of a rookie's mistake

Thank you anyways!